# Set group as secondary owner of a Site Collection

Tags: 2013, powershell, site-collection

All is in the subject. Is it possible to use an **AD group** (instead of a user) as the secondary owner of a Site collection ?

Both in graphical mode and with powershell (`New-SPSite ... -SecondaryOwnerAlias`) I can't do it.

For the "primary" owner, I already know (and confirm you) that it is possible.

**BUT,** after the creation of my site collection, if I wanna change this secondary owner, in graphical mode, I'm able to put an AD Group ...

So wondering if there is a way to add this group just after the creation of the site collection, in powershell. Or if it is possible directly in the `New-SPSite` command.

If someone can help :)

Thanks,

Nico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supported and it's supposed to be a user who is Administrator.

[image]

More to Read: [Change site collection administrators in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff631156.aspx#section1)

---

## Using PowerShell

When you use PowerShell you can set your Secondary Site Collection Administrator using this line:

```
Set-SPSite -Identity "MySiteCollectionUrl" -SecondaryOwnerAlias "AD\AdminGroup"
```

<strike>But I havn't tried this technique, but if you've tried it on Primary Site Collection Administrator, and got it functioning, I see no reason for this script not to work on the secondary SCA.</strike>

I have verified that this technique works, even if the result looks wierd both in Central Administration and in Powershell.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when you decide to change it, after the creation of the site collection, even if it tells you that you can't, you are able to do it... And btw in powershell i can put an AD group as Primary Administrator. 
Then, to put an AD group as Secondary administrator in graphical mode. You have to go on your site collection url, then parameters, Site collection Administrator, and here, you can put your group, tested it several times... So in powershell, how can i do that :)

Comment: @Nico I've updated my answer according to your comment

Comment: @Beeny Thank you again for you reply. I saw this, yes. But never tried. And i'm currently busy with a huge powershell script (for me, i'm a novice ;]), and I'll test it.

I was asking this, in order to saw people who tried this, and manage or not to do what I want.

As you, I cannot see any reason :) but it's Bill's idea ;D i'll post back if it works.

Thank you for your time.

And if someone else has already used it, let me know.

Comment: It works fine ! Set as an answer. Thank you @Benny