# Can we set security group as site collection administrator using CSOM in PowerShell in SharePoint Online - Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

Can we set security group as site collection administrator using CSOM in PowerShell in SharePoint Online - Office 365? I tried but getting error like "Company Administrator is not a valid user." Also is there any way to set primary and secondary site collection admin using CSOM in PowerShell? I am using sharepoint online -Office 365. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I know it’s [possible On Premise](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71887/set-group-as-secondary-owner-of-a-site-collection/71890#71890), where I have tried it myself and had it working properly (*even though it's not supported by Microsoft*). My guess is that it will work on SPO-Site as well. Simply run the following PowerShell Command:

```
Set-SPOsite -secondaryowneralias "domain\group"
```

Reference: [How we can add secondary administrator to sharepoint online site using powershell?](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/196119.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat old I know but just to say that officially at least, you cannot set the primary site collection administrator to be a group. However, you can add an AAD security group to the secondary administrators list.

You can do this directly via the web interface and though PowerShell using Set-SPOUser though you have to specify the group by the claims encoded identifier not by the name. So I assume (though I admit I've not yet actually tried) that you can also do this via CSOM.